# Height from the ground of aircrafts doors

Tags: boeing-737, airbus-a320, doors, airbus-a340, airbus-a220

I'm searching for the height from the ground of these AA/CC doors (front and back)

- Boeing 737-800
- Boeing 737-8200 (800-max)
- Airbus A319
- Airbus A320
- Airbus A321
- Airbus A220
- Airbus A340

I know only these approximate heights (in meters)

```
A/C              FRONT  BACK
----------------------------
Boeing 737-800          ~2.9
Boeing 737-8200 
Airbus A319
Airbus A320       ~3.4  ~3.4
Airbus A321
Airbus A220
Airbus A340
```

Is there a website with these specifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the airframers' airport planning guides will have this information.

[Airbus](https://aircraft.airbus.com/en/customer-care/fleet-wide-care/airport-operations-and-aircraft-characteristics/aircraft-characteristics)

[Boeing/McDonnell Douglas](https://www.boeing.com/commercial/airports/plan_manuals.page)

[Former Bombardier A220](https://eservices.aero.bombardier.com/wps/portal/eServices/Public/airportpublicationairbus/!ut/p/z1/jc_BCoJAEAbgZ-ng1ZnSyrptFFlaYiXZXMLCVkNdWTd9_aK6BCXNbYbv_2GAIAQqojrlkUpFEWWP_UCDo2lP5zbzcO0NnQn6o4E3WW52Bq5N2D8B_hiGQP_kWwC11--BnsRb2KxrYs_BVcCQ-bMu61uugVvjDVo6lkA8E6fXu6w4GRYHkvEllrHUb_JxTpQqq7GGGjZNo3MheBbrZ5Fr-C2SiEpB-CmhzIMQr_2sdlnnDuT3P20!/dz/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/) [CRJ and Dash 8](https://customer.aero.bombardier.com/webd/BAG/CustSite/BRAD/RACSDocument.nsf/vwWebPage/QuickLinks_EmergencyDocs?OpenDocument)

[Embraer](https://www.embraercommercialaviation.com/media-downloads/documents/#49-51-apm)

Door heights are usually specified as a range because, like a car, the landing gear compress as the aircraft is loaded and the center of gravity shifts.

Comment: Although it wasn't part of the question, a harder number  to obtain for some aircraft is the height from the doors to the bottom of the fuselage. This is a number which can come into play if landing with the gear up. Even more useful would be the height of the doors above the ground in various gear retracted/broken off situations, like nose gear retracted/missing, etc.

Comment: @StevePemberton It's not really relevant because you buy the firefighters ladders to reach the doors in normal conditions. If the gear collapses, then the height is decreased, so your ladders will satisfy that condition. Nonetheless, the charts list the height between the ground and the nacelles, and the ground and the fuselage, so just subtract the two. Rear doors are usually unusable in a nose gear collapse anyway (slides may not reach the ground), but the gear and door distances are all in the docs for a calculation.

Comment: user71659 - In a fire situation they can't always wait for firefighters with ladders. Jumping from a front door with a failed slide would likely cause injuries on most airliners, but if the plane is resting on its nose the front doors might be viable. Subtracting nacelle height only tells you the fuselage height above the ground if resting on the nacelles with the plane level, it doesn't give you the door distances from the ground. The rear doors are obviously not viable with a collapsed nose gear, but maybe in some cases they are with [collapsed main only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfclr.png)

Comment: This is a link only answer -- a prior such link only answer was deleted.

Comment: @StevePemberton That's why you subtract the fuselage-ground clearance height, or specific points like the belly fairing-ground clearance on the A320, which is slightly lower. That data is all in the documents.

Comment: user71659 - Yes I can see now that Airbus provides fuselage height above the ground, so by subtracting from door height above ground you can calculate door height above the fuselage. But Boeing doesn't seem to provide fuselage height above the ground. And it still wouldn't tell us what the expected door height above the ground is with various collapsed gear. These documents are for airports, maybe Flight Attendant training documents get into what my question is about. As I mentioned this info is harder to obtain, probably something not for public consumption.