# If the stairs are a universal height, how does a vertical gap occur? E.g. where the stairs fall short of the aircraft fuselage

Tags: safety

If the stairs are a universal height, how does a vertical gap occur? E.g. where the stairs fall short of the aircraft fuselage.

I have tried to find information regarding whether the stairs are universal in height and whether they can fall short leaving a vertical gap between the stairs and the aircraft.

Comment: Do you ask about the stairs at the Airport, that drive to the aircraft? Your question is a little unspecific in that regard.

Comment: Aircraft aren't exactly "at a universal height." Even for a given type, as passengers deplane, the struts extend, and the door can rise several inches going from full to empty. Is this perhaps the dynamic you're observing?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/101290/height-from-the-ground-of-aircrafts-doors

Answer (score 4):

Aircraft stairs are **not** a universal height. They almost all have some sort of mechanism that allows them to be adjusted to be used with different size aircraft.

The reason a vertical gap between the top of the stairs and the aircraft entrance occurs is because the aircraft suspension (for lack of a better word) will decompress as passengers deboard and the plane becomes lighter, which causes the aircraft body to rise. The opposite happens as passengers board and the plane becomes heavier.

Comment: while passenger weight is a factor, so is fuel and cargo. The struts on the landing gear will compress with additional weight. Stairs and jetways do have the ability to adjust their height. The person operating the jetway or stairs often get the height close enough and does not adjust it exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. What if this gap occurs as the passengers are climbing into the aircraft? As I would expect that the plane would be heavier and therefore a gap where the airstairs are below the entrance is unusual?

Comment: What if? If it becomes excessive the crew should adjust it, otherwise passengers simply move their feet as needed.  I'm not sure what you are confused about here...